# Are the close counts in real-time?

Tags: discussion, votes

If you are on the site at the 'questions' page and someone pages you with a comment, the red indicator will light up immediately.  Similarly, if you are on the 'questions' page the green indicator will light up as soon as you acquire a new badge.

If you are viewing a question that has been submitted to the review queue, does the close counter react in real-time? Or is a page refresh needed in order to see the current count?  Same question but for questions that have entered the review queue for edit approval.

Comment: Note: I was reading comments and the page flickered a bit and I thought the close vote counter adjusted. But it could have been the meds, hence this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [this has been raised before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191603/dynamically-update-close-vote-counts), and they don't update dynamically, despite some people wanting them to, from that thread.

So I guess the answer is no, you need to refresh the page.

Comment: I also think that there is a 3-minute window where you can answer a question *after it gets closed*.

Comment: The window isn't actually based on a time box, it's given to people who are already in the process of answering at the moment that the closure occurs. They then get [up to four hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/) to finish up.